Error: Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED when running npx expo run android after prebuild
I'm encountering an issue while setting up a React Native project with Expo and rnmapbox. After running expo prebuild --clean and npx expo run android, I get the following error during the build process:

Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-reanimated:debugCompileClasspath'.
Failed to transform core-ktx-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0) to match attributes...
Could not find core-ktx-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0).

Created a new Expo project.

Added rnmapbox to the project.

Run the following commands as per the documentation:

npx expo prebuild --clean

npx expo run android


